# Does this program with bounded recursion have undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, recursion, c++17, undefined-behavior

I know that infinite recursion or iteration is undefined behavior, but bounded is not. But, this program segment faults for most inputs. Does it have undefined behavior, why or why not? If it has undefined behavior, is there some modification I could make that would remove the undefined behavior?

```
#include <cstdint>

using bigint = ::std::uint64_t;
constexpr const bigint add_val = 1442695040888963407;
constexpr const bigint mult_val = 6364136223846793005;

bigint compute(bigint t)
{
   if (t > 1) {
      return add_val + compute(t * mult_val);
   } else {
      return 1;
   }
}

int main(int argc, char const * const argv[])
{
   return compute(argc < 0 ? -argc : argc);
}
```

This is basically using recursion to cycle through all the values of a [linear congruential random number generator with a period of 2^64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Parameters_in_common_use) so it's guaranteed to eventually come to 0 or 1.

I'm asking a very clear and specific question. Does this program that anybody can compile and run in its entirety invoke undefined behavior according to the C++ standard?

Comment: If the `t` passed in is greater than one, it will remain so until it overflows, no?

Comment: Well, according to my completely uneducated estimate, I would expect approximately 2^63 recursive calls (on average), before the parameter's value is one of the only two possible values that will terminate the recursion. So, do you have enough stack space, for 2^63 recursive calls?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - Well, that depends on what computer I'm running it on, doesn't it? I have no access to any computers with enough stack space. And I don't think anybody else on the planet right now does either. But that's not my question.

Comment: Looks like the `t` will be grater than 1 in almost every case. So will be called until overflows

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - Yes, there will be integer overflow, but integer overflow for unsigned values is defined by the standard if I'm not mistaken. There will almost certainly also be a stack overflow, but I don't know that the condition of a stack overflow is even talked about in the standard.

Comment: I guess the question is "does the standard impose restrictions on the maximum call stack size?". I suspect it doesn't and that stack overflow is a technically necessary non-compliance issue. But I'm not sure. Edit : The only mention of "overflow" I can find is about integers and the only mentions of "stack" are about `std::stack` and stack unwinding. Edit 2: The only mention of "recursive" is in *"Recursive calls are permitted, except to the `main` function."*.

Comment: It's unfortunately hard to search for information on stack overflows, because the term "stack overflow" is essentially useless as search engines don't distinguish the error from this site.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - That's a good point. I believe that these constants (chosen to be relatively prime with eachother and the number of values a uint64_t can hold) will simply result in a very long cycle. This is basically stepping through a linear congruential random number generator until you get to a certain value. But, I should pick constants where I can prove it.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - Fixed. When in doubt, steal from others. :-) I stole Knuth's parameters for a period 2^64 linear congruential random number generator.

Comment: You say *so it's guaranteed to eventually come to 0 or 1.*  Does that mean it might never result in a 0 and always a 1?

Comment: Possibly of interest: [standard discussion link](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1528.htm).

Comment: @NathanOliver - I don't know. I'd have to go find where Knuth comes up with the original parameters, or break out some math and see if I could figure it out myself. I relied on a Wikipedia entry that claimed Knuth created it and it had a period of exactly 2^64. I trusted that. My guess is that it will get back to either 0 or 1.

Comment: @Omnifarious: "*I know that infinite recursion or iteration is undefined behavior*" Citation needed (at least with regard to recursion). My understanding is that infinite recursion may violate resource limits, but that's not, strictly speaking, undefined behavior.

Comment: The standard doesn’t impose limits on this sort of thing, but implementations are allowed to. I don’t have a copy of the standard handy, but the magic word is “resource limit”.

Comment: There are no UB, the resource limit you hit may be due to an insufficient optimization. With gcc, the recursive call is transformed to a jump with -O2 optimization or -O3. https://godbolt.org/z/ILM4n2

Comment: @PeteBecker: Is there any particular source text which all conforming implementations would be required to process without hitting any resource limits?

Comment: @NicolBolas - I was under the impression it was UB for the same reason that infinite loops are UB. Basically, if a compiler notices recursion it may assume that it eventually terminates.

Comment: @Oliv - I was noticing that. *sigh* I made it too clean! I was going to replace it with Ackerman's function. :-) And I still may. Though someone has provided an excellent answer. Except, checking, ackerman's achieves its ridiculous results through fan-out rather than depth. :-(

Comment: @supercat — a conforming implementation can have resource limits so severe that it cannot compile any well-formed program. And a conforming implementation can display a message consisting solely of “.” when it compiles a program, and that can be documented as the diagnostic for any error in the code. Nobody would use either of those compilers.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Why, then, do some people believe that the Standard is intended to mandate everything that programmers should ever need to accommodate any task, and that programmers have no right to expect anything beyond what the Standard mandates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With thanks to 101010's standard link, I think the relevant phrase is

> ### 4.1 Implementation compliance [intro.compliance]
>
> (2.1) - If a program contains no violations of the rules in this document, a conforming implementation shall, *within its resource limits*, accept and correctly execute that program.

and

> ### Annex B (informative)
>
> ### Implementation quantities [implimits]

mostly addresses compiler limitations (max symbol length, characters per line etc.), but the language sounds related:

> 1. Because computers are finite, C++ implementations are inevitably limited in the size of the programs they can successfully process. **Every implementation shall document those limitations where known**. This documentation may cite fixed limits where they exist, say how to compute variable limits as a function of available resources, or say that fixed limits do not exist or are unknown.
> 2. The limits may constrain quantities that include those described below or others ...

So, the standard doesn't say which quantities may be limited by an implementation, or give anything other than guidelines for the minimum values of those limits it does describe.

If your compiler doesn't document its stack depth limit, I guess it may be non-conforming according to the **bold** sentence, but a statement that *"stack depth is limited by these runtime properties"* might be sufficient..

> Does this program that anybody can compile and run in its entirety invoke undefined behavior according to the C++ standard?

No. But per 4.1/2.1 implementations are permitted to fail to compile, or fail correctly to execute, a correct program.

Comment: This answer is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: I do have one quibble though. Wouldn't the maximum stack size be a limit on the data processing system on which the implementation ran, and not an implementation limit?

Comment: Would the Standard forbid an implementation whose resource constraints would be insufficient to run any programs whatsoever in the absence of optimizations, but which would be capable of "optimizing" a vaguely-defined set of programs so that they could run?

Comment: The standard can only provide a way to judge whether an implementation is conformant, it can't ban anything. Anyway, I suspect that such an implementation would have difficulty attracting customers, whether technically conforming or not.

Comment: @Omnifarious, in practice there are multiple limits: max possible stack size in a given addressing mode, max supported by a compiler if that differs, max permitted by runtime system limits, max by runtime user limits, and max actually accessible at a given moment. AFAIK they're all grouped into the "Implementation"  by the standard.

Answer (score 2):

Facts first, from draft standard [N4800](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/n4800.pdf) §7.1/P4  [expr.pre] (**Emphasis Mine**):

> **If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for
>   its type, the behavior is undefined.** [Note: Treatment of division by
>   zero, forming a remainder using a zero divisor, and all floating-point
>   exceptions vary among machines, and is sometimes adjustable by a
>   library function. — end note]

Also the clause §6.7.1/p2 Fundamental types [basic.fundamental] (**Emphasis Mine**):

> For each of the standard signed integer types, there exists a
>   corresponding (but different) standard unsigned integer type:
>   “unsigned char”, “unsigned short int”, “unsigned int”, “unsigned long
>   int”, and “unsigned long long int”. Likewise, for each of the extended
>   signed integer types, there exists a corresponding extended unsigned
>   integer type. The standard and extended unsigned integer types are
>   collectively called unsigned integer types. An unsigned integer type
>   has the same range exponent N as the corresponding signed integer
>   type. **The range of representable values for the unsigned type is 0
>   to 2^N − 1 (inclusive); arithmetic for the unsigned type is performed
>   modulo 2^N . [Note: Unsigned  arithmetic does not overflow. Overflow
>   for signed arithmetic yields undefined behavior (7.1). — end note]**

Also §5.13.2/p2 Integer literals [lex.icon]

> The type of an integer literal is the first of the corresponding list
>   in Table 7 in which its value can be represented.

[image]

Also §7.4 Usual arithmetic conversions [expr.arith.conv]

> (1.5) — Otherwise, the integral promotions (7.3.6) shall be performed
>   on both operands<sup>60</sup>. Then the following rules shall be applied to the
>   promoted operands:
>
> - (1.5.1) — If both operands have the same type, no further conversion is needed.
> - (1.5.2) — Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned integer types, the operand with the type of lesser
>     integer conversion rank shall be converted to the type of the operand
>     with greater rank.
> - (1.5.3) — Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater than or equal to the rank of the type of the other
>     operand, the operand with signed integer type shall be converted to
>     the type of the operand with unsigned integer type.
> - (1.5.4) — Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent all of the values of the type of the operand with
>     unsigned integer type, the operand with unsigned integer type shall be
>     converted to the type of the operand with signed integer type.
> - (1.5.5) — Otherwise, both operands shall be converted to the unsigned integer type corresponding to the type of the operand with
>     signed integer type

So the question is: Are the arithmetic results in this program mathematically defined and within the range of representable values for its types. More specifically, is the expression `1442695040888963407 + compute(t * 6364136223846793005)` within the range of representable values for its types?

For this to happen the type of integer literals 1442695040888963407 and 6364136223846793005 must fall to lesser or equal [conversion rank](http://www.enseignement.polytechnique.fr/informatique/INF478/docs/Cpp/en/c/language/integer_conversion_rank.html) with `std::uint64_t` so that the results convert to `std::uint64_t`. Unfortunatelly, there's no such guarantee.

Thus, for your program to avoid UB I would mark the integer literals with `LU`.

```
bigint compute(bigint t)
{
   if (t > 1) {
      return 1442695040888963407LU + compute(t * 6364136223846793005LU);
   } else {
      return 1;
   }
}
```

Now, as to why you get segmentation fault, is due to the fact that you overflow your stack. Although, the above program theoretically doesn't have infinite number of recursions which is UB, the number of recursions exhausts your machine's resources.

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that any practical system will ever exist with integer types that would cause the indicated constants to promote to a type with higher rank than `uint64_t`?  Is any useful purpose served by trying to accommodate such a possibility?

Comment: I will modify my program so that this answer no longer applies. :-) My question was meant to be about whether or not the behavior of a program that for all practical purposes will have a stack overflow even though the recursion is definitely bounded. And I realize it will have a stack overflow on all current machines. The question is, is the program invoking undefined behavior. :-) It's a really good answer though. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The Standard authors of the Standard recognized that different implementations could and should differ in the range of programs that they could process usefully.  While the Standard could perhaps have specified that quality implementations should try to usefully process as wide a range of tasks as practical--with the definition of "practicality" left to the implementer's judgment--but they probably thought such a notion would be self-evident.

If the term "Undefined Behavior" is applied to every program for which the Standard would impose no requirements, then all programs would invoke Undefined Behavior except for one caveat: a conforming implementation must be capable of processing at least one--possibly contrived and useless--program in the manner defined by the Standard.  Consequently, if a program would not perform any action which the Standard characterizes as Undefined Behavior, the Standard would define the behavior of the program *when run by a conforming implementation that was incapable of running any other program in the manner defined by the Standard*.  It imposes no behavior upon the behavior of any program in any other circumstance.